# Whenever a new version of Ubuntu is released do I need to re-download Ubuntu?

Tags: updates

Let's say if I have Xenial Xerus, when a new version (let's say Yakkety Yak) comes out will I have to go to the website and install it or will I just have to do the update command and it save all my data and update to the new version?

Comment: See [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) and [Upgrade from a previous version of Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, when I went from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 16.10 LTS (Yakkety Yay) I got a notification in the software updater saying there is a new version of Ubuntu available. There was a button to install & download it.

Also you can go in software and updates -> updates -> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version. From there you can select whether you want to be notified about new Ubuntu versions.

Just a warning that you can't roll back from 16.10 to 16.04 without reinstall all of Ubuntu (aka. like the first time you installed Ubuntu)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to latest version of Ubuntu by using this command

`sudo do-release-upgrade`

Unfortunately you can't rollback to the older version again.

One more thing is make sure that you are not using desktop environment other than unity otherwise this command will break your system.

Hope it helps